# How to dynamically manage the asp.net control editable state based on roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am using asp.net with .net framework version 4.0.

I have a page with multiple input/select controls like text box, drop down list check boxes etc. This page can be access by different types of users and based on user type every control of page are configurable for edit access(enabled/disabled), So to achieve this requirement we have stored the every control id ,user type and accessible rights (enabled/disabled) on database table. On page_load we fetch the data from configuration table then find the each control on page and set the enabled property.

This approach working so far, but I want to handle it with some other possible or any inbuilt functionality of asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Storing Control IDs is tightly couple to UI. I personally like to store features in database instead of Control IDs.

Main reason is when a new feature is added, you just need to modify the UI *(add or remove controls)* based on the feature. If you later have to migrate to different UI such as ASP.Net MVC or UWA, you can convert them easily.

For example, I store the following in database.

```
UserId | Insert | Update | Delete
---------------------------------
   1   |  True  | True   | False
   2   |  False | False  | False
```

In web form, you can use Panel control to show or hide multiple controls based on the feature.

Comment: Thanks, My concern is not about insert update or delet operation this is already implemented on top level sequirity, we have a second level sequirity where user can enter data in contols based on specific permission given to particular user or user type.  For example we have 40 input control in page where some user/ user group can enter data in only 25 controle, and that control my exists on on a diffrent panels.

Comment: Insert, Update Delete are just hypothetical examples. The bottom-line is do not store Control IDs which is not a good design; instead, you want to store features *such as AllowPurchase*. Then hide ***Panel*** according to the feature. *When you later migrate to MVC, you can easily replace Panel with **PartialView**.*